# Draw graph in QGis on selection (of multiple points)

Tags: qgis

The issue is that I have a geopackage with some points. One of the attribute columns stores the date information. My rather naive question would be, without actually thinking about any kind of implementation, if it is possible to interactively select some points and draw some kind of graph to visualize quickly the dates of those points?

I know there are the Qgis Actions and I already some examples a while ago. But can I somehow combine this with the current selection (of potentially multiple points) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very easily: right click on the layer / `properties / diagrams` tab and define a diagram there - see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=diagrams#diagrams-properties). To see only diagrams for selected features, choose a data driven override for `Show diagram` and paste the expression `is_selected( )`, see screenshot.

Now, all diagrams disappear. Once you select one or more features, diagrams show up for these features.

[image]

Comment: thank you very very much!! The thing is, that I want one histogram for all the selected features and not one histogram for each point that I select. Is that possible here as well? Sorry for the naive question

Comment: So you want to aggregate the values of all the selected features, do I understand this right? So in the screenshot above for the 6 selected features you want to sum up all the "red" values, all "blue" ones and so on?

Comment: Yes exactly:) That is what I had in mind more or less

Comment: It is possible to use expressions instead of attribute values to generate diagrams. However, I tried different aggregate functions and QGIS seems to have problem with these for generating the input of diagrams. I used among others `sum( "attribute" , is_selected())` for pie charts. QGIS draws the circle, but no pies.

Comment: There is a workaround, however: you can use geometry genarators to create your own pie charts with `wedge_buffer`. It is not so straightforward - you have to calculate the angle for each pie: convert the procentual share of each pie to it's share of 360 degrees. This here works to create the first pie, pie-size corresponds to the total number:
`wedge_buffer( centroid ($geometry),
360/100*sum( "attribute" , is_selected()) / sum ( "total" , is_selected())*100/2, 
360/100*sum( "attribute" , is_selected()) / sum ( "total" , is_selected())*100, 
sum ( "total" , is_selected()) / 4)`

Comment: As the QGIS pie charts renderer does not work as expected, I asked a new question about that, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382725/pie-charts-in-qgis-attributes-generated-with-expressions-not-working-when-using

Comment: oh wow, sorry for my late answer!! I'll definitly try this out as soon as possible. Thank you very very much:)!!